# What is a factory class method in Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm trying to build an App which required me to install the Couchbase-lite pod. When I tried to initialize a class, it said it was NS_UNAVAILABLE and it told me to use the factory class methods instead. How do I go about this in a general way in using the 'Factory class methods'?

Say for example I did this:

```
class Polyline: CBLModel {

init() {        // the error starts here that says init is unavailable

    /* code here */

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory method is a class function that creates an instance of your class.

[Couchbase documentation says](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/model/index.html) that you should follow a pattern that bypasses `init` altogether:

> Remember that every model has a one-to-one association with a document in the database. `CBLModel` has no public initializer methods, and you should not implement any yourself in subclasses.

Creating new polylines should be done as follows:

```
let poly = Polyline(forNewDocumentInDatabase: database)
```

If you need custom initialization, it needs to go into a factory method as well:

```
class Polyline : CBLModel {
    @NSManaged var x : Int
    @NSManaged var y : Int

    class func newPolylineInDatabase(database: CBLDatabase, withX x: Int andY y:Int)
    -> Polyline {
        let res = Polyline(forNewDocumentInDatabase: database)
        res.x = x
        res.y = y
        return res
    }
}
```